# How to avoid iOS UITableView animation to block user interaction with table

Tags: ios, uitableview, animation, insert

I have a timer that insert a new item on a tableview every 2 seconds, it is required that the tableview shows this new line insertion with an animation of 1 second, the problem is that the user interaction is blocked while the tableview insert animation is happening, I tryied to pass as option for the animation the constant UIViewAnimationOptions.AllowUserInteraction, but it did not worked. What I need is that the user can interact with the tableview, selecting cells, scrolling etc even during the animation sequence. Any ideias ? The code for the problem example is on github

https://github.com/munhra/TableAnimationProblem

This video shows the not desired behavior
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jb7dnCv5wXw&feature=youtu.be

Comment: With 1 second of animation and allowing the user to interact with the tableview will always create problems for you. Either you disable the interaction will the datasource is being changed and table being updated. Or you limit the animation to a very small time.

Comment: Even with a small time animation, I cannot ensure that the table will be 100% of time user enabled, What I'm searching is a way to enable the user interaction during the animation. Do you know if there is a way ?

Comment: My understanding is that if the datasource is changing and the user is interacting with the tableview during that period, it will always have the probability of crash, and as your user base increases you will find more of these crashes. (I am currently facing this issue in one of my app. I may be wrong about this though, there could be an alternate approach to this.)